# What does the error: "Module 'myApp' has verification error 2733 at offset 1646" mean

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, lwuit

I get the following error:

> Module 'myApp' has verification error
>   2733 at offset 1646

and this is my code:

```
public class Midlet extends net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication{

public static void main(String[] argv) {
     new Midlet().startApp();
}

public void startApp() {
    System.out.println("tada!");
}

public void pauseApp() {
    System.out.println("PauseApp ...zzzz...");
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    System.out.println("destroyed: " + unconditional);
}

public void notifyDestroyed() {
    System.exit(0);
}

public void platformRequest(String s) {
    net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage(s);
}
```

}

My Imports "LWUIT", "BlackberryPort" and "LWUIT4IO".

It builds without errors, I get the error when I try to start up the app.

What does this error mean?

Comment: I found the following but it wasn't very usefull to me: http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800708/800647/Support_-_MIDlet_has_verification_error_at_offset.html?nodeid=800711&vernum=0

Comment: I have no experience with MIDlets but I can tell you that you can't override UiApplication with a MIDlet.  None of those methods were actually overriden. You should either extend MIDlet or use the BlackBerry specific UI APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you signed your app? Browser integration requires app signing.

Also take a look at the [LWUIT blog](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2009/01/rim-blackberry-verification-errors.html) explains the verification errors.